# Replaces page with image instead of adding it

Tags: javascript

The below code automagically removes all of my Headings and Paragraphs and just loads the pictures in question. I want the image to be added, not replacing the text. Why is this occuring?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
<p id="flipDisplay"></p>
<button onclick="display()">Flip the Coin!</button>
<script>
  function coinFlip() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
  }
  function display() {
    if (coinFlip()) {
      document.write('<img src="./tflip.png">');
    } else {
      document.write('<img src="./ctflip.png">');
    }
  }
</script>
<!--<a><img src=javacript:flip></a> -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what about `.html()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `document.write` we can append the image to an element on the screen.  I am using the `id="flipDisplay"` paragraph tag to hold the image here.

I am creating an img element then using a new `showImage` function to wipe out the old contents of `flipDisplay` and append the new result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>My Web Page</h1>
<p>My paragraph.</p>
<p id="flipDisplay"></p>
<button onclick="display()">Flip the Coin!</button>
<script>
  function coinFlip() {
    return (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 0);
  }
  function display() {
    if (coinFlip()) {      
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "./tFlip.png";    
      showImage(img);         
    } else {      
      var img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = "./ctflip.png";
      showImage(img);
    }
  }

  function showImage(img){
      var display = document.getElementById("flipDisplay");
      display.innerHTML = '';
      display.appendChild(img);
  }
</script>
<!--<a><img src=javacript:flip></a> -->
</body>
</html>
```

I am avoiding `document.write` because when used after the page has been loaded, it will clear the DOM and insert only what was supplied to the write.  Interactive pages tend to use other methods when modifying the page, such as the example above.

Comment: I think the answer should also mention that, after the DOM has been built, a call to `document.write` will reset the DOM and create a document with only an `img` tag.

Comment: Good point, I should have explained the shift to a different strategy. Added an edit.